# JSON array of Objects not accessible by index, only by 'response.data'

Tags: javascript, json, axios, recharts

I'm trying to parse a JSON array:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "dates":"02/01/2021-02/14/2021",
         "profit":23002,"revenue":230
      },...
   ]
}
```

I want this parsed JSON object to be passed into recharts as data but when I `console.log` the function that returns `res.data` it is read as `undefined`. In the below code the first console log gives me data, but the second one is undefined. Any direction would be helpful.

```
const getData = () => {
    axios.get(`https hidden for privacy reasons`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Ran into error");
      })
  }


console.log(getData())
```

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` is an asynchronous function with a callback. This type of function does not return data - instead the data is only accessible within the scope of the provided callback, function i.e. within the

```
res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
      }
```

anonymous function.

Note that your `getData` function does not contain a `return` statement and therefore will return an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

You want `getData` to return the result of the Axios get:

```js
const getData = () => {
    return axios.get(`https hidden for privacy reasons`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Ran into error");
      })
  }
```

And then you'll need to `Promise.then` (or `await`) the result, since `getData` is a promise:

```js
  getData().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```